# Universal Reference and Named Parameter Ideom

Tags: c++11, gcc, forwarding-reference

I wrote this code and compile with gcc.
I expected to get result "2", but result was "0".

Other compiler clang and vc prints "2".
Is it undefined behaviour or not?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Test {
    Test& inc() {
        ++value;
        return *this;
    }

    int value = 1;
};

int main() {
    auto&& t = Test().inc(); // The life-time of the temporary might extended.
    printf("%d\n", t.value); // gcc prints "0". dangling reference?

    return 0;
}
```

c.f. build reslut on http://rextester.com

- [gcc result](http://rextester.com/QUDC93238)
- [clang result](http://rextester.com/PWM80327)
- [vc result](http://rextester.com/PQKLE85423)

Comment: http://rextester.com/GBM44684

Comment: I misteke about auto deducing. `auto&& t = Test().inc()`  is not `auto&& t = Test(); t.inc();`. Thank you @Quentin !

Comment: `gcc-7 -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope` can detect this err.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forwarding reference (that's what universal references have been renamed to) is irrelevant -- you would observe the same behaviour with a regular reference.

The issue is that the `Test`'s lifetime is not extended, because it is not *directly* bound to the reference, as `auto &&t = Test();` would be. Instead, its member function returns an lvalue reference, which is used to deduce and initialize `t` as a `Test &` (you can check this via `decltype(t)`). Then the temporary is destructed, the reference is now dangling, and using it is undefined behaviour.